# Cannot convert UnityEngine.Component to Quest

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on a game and I am implementing a quest system. I am trying to assign the quest script to the QuestGiver NPC that I will have but I am receiving an error. My error is Cannot convert UnityEngine.Components to Quest.

This is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class QuestGiver : NPC
{
    public bool AssignedQuest { get; set; }
    public bool Helped { get; set; }
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject quests;
    [SerializeField]
    private string questType;
    private Quest Quests { get; set; }


    public CharacterController2D player;


    public override void Interact()
    {
        base.Interact();
        if (!AssignedQuest && !Helped)
        {
            //assign
        }
        else if (AssignedQuest && !Helped)
        {
            // check
        }
    }

    void AssignQuest()
    {
        AssignedQuest = true;
        Quests = (Quest)quests.AddComponent(System.Type.GetType("").ToString());
        
    }
```

This is my code for Quest

```
    public class Quest 
{
    public List<QuestGoal> Goals { get; set; } = new List<QuestGoal>();

    public string QuestName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int ExpRewards { get; set; }
    public int CurrencyReward { get; set; }
    public Item ItemReward { get; set; }
    public bool Completed { get; set; }

    public void CheckGoals()
    {
        Completed = Goals.All(q => q.Completed);
        if (Completed) GiveReward();
        
    }
    public void GiveReward()
    {
        if (ItemReward != null)
        {
            Inventory.inventory.Add(ItemReward);
        }
    }
```

The error occurs on the following part of AssignQuest();

```
Quests = (Quest)quests.AddComponent(System.Type.GetType("").ToString());
```

Please help if possible, Thank you!

Comment: Could you show the code for `Quest`? Does it at some point inherit from `Component` at all? Also in general instead of the wild contruct you are using you would rather use `Quets = quets.AddComponent<Quest>();` and definitely not use `GetType("")` which will return `null` anyway

Comment: @derHugo I have updated the question with the Quest code. You are correct, I don't think it inherits from Component at all. I think I can fix this by inheriting Quest from MonoBehaviour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix my issue with some guidance from @derHugo
my Quest class was not inheriting anything so I change Quest to

```
public class Quest : MonoBehaviour{

//...rest of my code for this

}
```

I also changed the AssignQuest(); to the following

```
void AssignQuest()
{
    AssignedQuest = true;
    Quest = quests.AddComponent<Quest>();
}
```

This fixed my issue.

Comment: But if so far it didn't inherit from `MonoBehaviour` but basically still worked .. then do you really need it as a `MonoBeuaviour`?

Comment: @derHugo I didnt think I needed MonoBehaviour but adding that is the only thing that gets rid of the error

Comment: And what about not inherit from `MonoBehaviour` but simply make it `Quests = new Quest();` as usual?

Comment: So I tried the Quest = new Quest() and that worked, Thank you. I was thinking of adding components but just doing a new quest like you suggest should give me the same result for this. Thank you for your help @derHugo . I apologize for the noobie questions.